# Python - Get string after and before a Character

Tags: python, substring, charindex

I've this strings:

```
"I have been working - 8h by day"
"Like - 9H by Month"
```

I'm trying to get the number of Hours. Basically I'm trying to get this output:

```
8
9
```

I try this but without success:

```
print(myString.split("H",1)[1] )
```

But I'm getting this:

```
builtins.IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I get the string after "-" and before "H" in Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the issue you have is the `"I have been working - 8h by day"` has no `"H"` in it, so when you split by "H" there is only one element in list.

you could find it using regex

```
import re
pattern = r'\d(?=[h|H])'
data = ["I have been working - 8h by day",
        "Like - 9H by Month"]

for item in data:
    print re.findall(pattern, item)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use regex**

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = ["I have been working - 8h by day", "Like - 9H by Month"]
for i in s:
    print(re.findall("\d+H" ,i, flags=re.I))
```

**Output:**

```
['8']
['9']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall` to match all digits only if followed by an `h` or `H`:

```
import re
s = ["I have been working - 8h by day", "Like - 9H by Month"]
new_s = [re.findall('\d+(?=H)', i, flags=re.I)[0] for i in s]
```

Output:

```
['8', '9']
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a danger with this that it will split on other Hs and that it keeps the whole string (to resolve this write a better expression with regex).

to resolve your code as is:

```
print(myString.split("H",1)[0][::-1][0])
```